# Does an accelerating neutron produce electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, neutrons

I believe both protons and electrons do produce e/m radiation if accelerated, but what about a neutron which is made up of, or at least decays to, an electron and a proton?

If accelerating a neutron does not produce e/m radiation, why not? Why do not both the components produce waves? Or is it perhaps that they in fact do, but cancel each other out?

Comment: There's radiation from an accelerated neutron, but it is not *electric dipole* radiation, so it is weaker.  The lowest multipole that contributes is, I believe, the magnetic quadrupole.

Comment: It is e/m radiation? If so, what is actually happening -- is the proton component emitting radiation and also the electron and is there in fact some sort of cancellation? If there is cancellation, why do we see anything at all?

Comment: This question and answer explores this theme  in the answers, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136018/how-is-it-possible-to-accelerate-a-neutron . It cannot be accelerated to high energies, but it can in the "ultra cold neutron" experiments. answer by Menger Sponge .

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: [Does an accelerating electric dipole radiate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391558/does-an-accelerating-electric-dipole-radiate)